# Nested for loops with large data set

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, large-data

I have a list of sublists each of which consists of one or more strings. I am comparing each string in one sublist to every other string in the other sublists. This consists of writing two for loops. However, my data set is ~5000 sublists, which means my program keeps running forever unless I run the code in increments of 500 sublists. How do I change the flow of this program so I can still look at all j values corresponding to each i, and yet be able to run the program for ~5000 sublists. (wn is Wordnet library) 
Here's part of my code:

```
for i in range(len(somelist)):
    if i == len(somelist)-1: #if the last sublist, do not compare
        break
    title_former  = somelist[i]

    for word in title_former:
        singular = wn.morphy(word) #convert to singular
        if singular == None:
            pass 
        elif singular != None:
            newWordSyn  = getNewWordSyn(word,singular)
            if not newWordSyn:
                uncounted_words.append(word)
            else:
                for j in range(i+1,len(somelist)):
                    title_latter = somelist[j]
                    for word1 in title_latter:
                        singular1 = wn.morphy(word1) 
                        if singular1 == None:
                            uncounted_words.append(word1)
                        elif singular1 != None:
                            newWordSyn1      = getNewWordSyn(word1,singular1)
                            tempSimilarity  = newWordSyn.wup_similarity(newWordSyn1)
```

Example:

```
Input = [['space', 'invaders'], ['draw']]
Output= {('space','draw'):0.5,('invaders','draw'):0.2}
```

The output is a dictionary with corresponding string pair tuple and their similarity value. The above code snippet is not complete.

Comment: can you give us a small example input and expected output

Comment: now I see what you are trying to do ... hmmmm ... that may just be slow...

Comment: It would've been okay if it was slow, but it hardly runs :(

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this but I doubt it will be faster (and you will probably need to change the distance function)

```py
    def dist(s1,s2):
        return sum([i!=j for i,j in zip(s1,s2)]) + abs(len(s1)-len(s2))

    dict([((k,v),dist(k,v)) for k,v in itertools.product(Input1,Input2)]
```

Comment: whoops was missing a parentheses

Comment: Hmm, I'm unsure how to translate my code into this. By distance, do you mean the similarity between the strings?

Comment: yeah it looks like you are using some library function `newWordSyn.wup_similarity(newWordSyn1)` but i dont know anything about that library so im not sure what its doing or how long that calculation is taking ...

Comment: Yeah, but I isn't the main problem the fact that I have  nested for loops and a huge data set and not necessarily the library method?

Comment: you could profile it with `python -m cprofile myscript.py`  and then look at the output in runsnakerun

Answer (score 1):

How about doing a bit of preprocessing instead of doing a bunch of operations over and over? I did not test this, but you get the idea; you need to take anything you can out of the loop.

```
# Preprocessing:
unencountered_words = []
preprocessed_somelist = []
for sublist in somelist:
    new_sublist = []
    preprocessed_somelist.append(new_sublist)
    for word in sublist:
        temp = wn.morphy(word)
        if temp:
            new_sublist.append(temp)
        else:
            unencountered_words.append(word)

# Nested loops:
for i in range(len(preprocessed_somelist) - 1): #equivalent to your logic
    for word in preprocessed_somelist[i]:
            for j in range(i+1, len(preprocessed_somelist)):
                   for word1 in preprocessed_somelist[j]:
                            tempSimilarity  = newWordSyn.wup_similarity(newWordSyn1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is always going to have scaling issues, because you're doing n^2 string comparisons. Julius' optimization is certainly a good starting point.

The next thing you can do is store similarity results so you don't have to compare the same words repeatedly.

One other optimisation you can make is store comparisons of words and reuse them if the same words are encountered.

```
key = (newWordSyn, newWordSyn1)
if key in prevCompared:
    tempSimilarity  = prevCompared[(word, word1)]
else:
    tempSimilarity  = newWordSyn.wup_similarity(newWordSyn1)
    prevCompared[key] = tempSimilarity
    prevCompared[(newWordSyn1, newWordSyn)] = tempSimilarity
```

This only helps if you will see a lot of the same word combination, but i think wup_similarity is quite expensive.